# Как получить заголовки пакетов IP

Tags: ip, udp, winsock, c++

Сразу прошу прощение за свою неграмотность, я только начал изучать работу с сетью в С++.
Нашёл в интернете коды простейших клиентской и серверной программ, в которых используются вышеуказанные вещи. Программы передают пакеты, принимают пакеты, всё хорошо. Но мне нужно получить **доступ к заголовкам пакетов IP** - как чтение заголовков после приёма, так и изменение их по своему усмотрению при передаче. Конкретно, к полям: **ToS, TTL и параметры**.

Как это осуществить?

Клиент и сервер взяты отсюда: http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=223563

Comment: Вам надо посмотреть информацию на тему raw sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте функции setsockopt и getsockopt. Они устанавливают и получают параметры сокета для протоколов разного уровня. Параметры, интересные вам находятся на IP-уровне, соответственно вам нужно использовать что-то вроде
`setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TOS, &tos_val, sizeof(tos_val))` и 
`setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl_val, sizeof(ttl_val))`

Ссылки на MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738586(v=vs.85).aspx